# Passing a parameter to the function in Maxima CAS

Tags: list, grep, syntax-error, locale, maxima

I have [a program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) im Maxima CAS:

```
kill(all);
remvalue(all);


GivePart(n):=(
    [Part, iMax],

    if (n>20) then iMax:10
      else iMax : 250,
    Part : makelist(i, i, 0, iMax)   )$

GiveList(iMax):=(
    [Part, PartList ],
    PartList:[],
    for i:1 thru iMax step 1 do (
        Part:  GivePart(i),
        PartList : cons(Part, PartList)
    ),
    PartList
)$

pp:GiveList(60)$
length(pp);
```

It creates a list pp.

**The length of pp  should be  60 but is 21.**

Program has 2 functions and iMax which is

- parameter to second function
- local variable in the first function

Program runs without any error messeges.

I have checked the source code of Maxima CAS

```
grep -wnR "iMax"
```

and iMax is not used in Maxima CAS code

I know how to **solve the problem**: change name of local variable in first function:

```
kill(all);
remvalue(all);
GivePart(n):=(
    [Part, i_Max],

    if (n>20) then i_Max:10
      else i_Max : 250,
    Part : makelist(i, i, 0, i_Max)  )$

GiveList(iMax):=(
    [Part, PartList ],
    PartList:[],
    for i:1 thru iMax step 1 do (
        Part:  GivePart(i),
        PartList : cons(Part, PartList)
    ),
    PartList
)$


pp:GiveList(60)$

length(pp);
```

Now the length of pp is 60 ( good).

**What is the cause of the problem ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be

```
GivePart(n):=(
    [Part, iMax],
```

which is not correct, it should be

```
GivePart(n):=block(
    [Part, iMax],
```

Outside of `block`, `[Part, iMax]` is not recognized as a list of local variables, and `iMax` has the value that was bound when `GiveList` was called (this is a consequence of Maxima's "dynamic scope" policy).

I see that `GiveList` also has a missing `block` which needs to be corrected.

Comment: What is the reason that iMax is equal to 21 ? In GivePart it has value 10 or 250.

Comment: Within `GivePart`, `iMax` is assigned a value (10 or 250). But `iMax` is also the loop variable in `GiveList` (because of dynamic scope). Changing the loop variable causes the loop to terminate. If you change `if (n>20) ...` to `if (n>29) ...` you'll get 30 items in the output list.

Comment: @ Robert Dodier. Is it possible that Maxima parser find such error and give a warning?

Comment: Not sure which error you mean. (1) Maybe you mean `([foo, bar], ...)` instead of `block([foo, bar], ...)`. Since `([foo, bar], ...)` is a valid (if not very useful) construct, I don't know how we would give an error about it. (2) Maybe you mean changing a loop variable in a function called from the loop. The right way to fix that is to implement lexical scope instead of dynamic scope. Lexical scope has been a topic for discussion many times over the years. Perhaps someday it will be implemented.

Comment: Dodier I mean ([foo, bar], ...) instead of block([foo, bar], ...). It could be warning only : "foo, bar variables are not local. If you wnat it add block "

Comment: How to callify such error : semantic , logical ? For sure it is silent.

Comment: I've pushed commit 58a5a40 which implements a parser warning for ([foo, bar], ...). I expect it will appear in the next released version (5.42); in the meantime it is in the Git version.